# Is "PhD" a title?

Tags: titles

When in forms you are asked to write your title/position. Can you write your degree? For example "PhD in Software Engineering"? Can that fit well in a title/position field?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for Workplace SE.

Answer (score 2):

> [A **PhD**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Doctor-of-Philosophy) is a university degree and once you have a PhD, you can be
>   called "*Dr*.

=> Qualification:  PhD in Software Engineering

[**Title** is a name that describes someone’s position or *job*:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/title) Doctor, Software engineer

Answer (score 1):

'PhD in software engineering' appears to be a degree qualification, and hence does not qualify as a job title or position.

The possible exception would be if you are currently studying for some kind of PhD that involves an internship arrangement (such as an Industrial PhD) where you have explicit work-related duties or responsibilities, in which case it might be appropriate to mention the qualification. For instance:

> Interning as a researcher (towards an Industrial PhD in software engineering)

Comment: I would have said that someone studying for a PhD was a *Research Student*, or *Post-Graduate Student*. *PhD* is an academic qualification, which can be appended after a person's name after it has been awarded. It is not their occupational title.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, PhD is a degree and a postnomial.  The associated title is 'Doctor' or 'Dr' (the postnomial distinguishes it from an MD)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working towards your PhD, then it is often acceptable to use the term ["PhD Candidate" as your job title](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/phd-candidate-vs-phd-student), however, policies can sometimes be quite strict and precise at your academic institution, so speak with your career adviser office.

If you have obtained your PhD and are currently working in a mentored scholarship position, then [some form of "Postdoc"](http://www.nationalpostdoc.org/policy-22/what-is-a-postdoc) is an acceptable job title. Again, your employer will likely have highly specific guidance on this.

The above can also be used to describe past situations.

If you have a PhD but you are not working, then you do not have a job title.